# Spread a class instance

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to spread a class instance?
I have been trying to but I keep getting an empty object returned.
What I've tried:

```
const ctx = new AudioContext()
const example = {...ctx}


//prints {}
console.log(example)
```

I've also tried using `Object.assign` and encountered the same thing.
What am I missing here?

**Something to note:** It works on custom classes.

Comment: why are you wanting to spread a builtin type?

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm hoping to override certain properties

Comment: i would avoid doing that and perhaps just using your own facade.

Comment: An `AudioContext` probably has no own enumerable properties. But why would you want to do this? Better explicitly copy those parts of the data that you are actually interested in. Copying an instance won't work anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `for...in` loop for this purpose.

```js
const ctx = new AudioContext();
const toObject = o => {
  const res = {};//or Object.create(null)
  for(const key in o) res[key] = o[key];
  return res;
};
console.log(toObject(ctx));
```